# Remove common file name convention within html on constantly

Tags: javascript, regex, string

On a page that is pulling updates as a live feed - there are files generated that end _s.png

I want to remove _s from every instance. I think the below should work for one instance - however it's not going to keep checking the page.

```
document.onload = function {
    var str = document.getElementByClass("icon").innerHTML;
    var res = str.replace("_s", "");
    document.getElementByClass("icon").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you need to remove all occurrences? Say, with `var res = str.replace(/_s\.png/g, ".png");`?

Comment: _“however it's not going to keep checking the page”_ – of course it is not, because the document’s load event happens only once. If you want it to periodically check, then use setTimeout or setInterval. (But if possible this should not be done via a timer interval, but rather directly when the updates are pulled/inserted into the document. You weren’t specific about what technique you are using there, but check if it provides events or callbacks for that.)

Comment: `getElementByClass` ==> getElement**s**ByClass**Name**. And, if there are multiple elements with that class, iterate over them using `for()` and apply the changes individually.

Comment: @Tushar: Even if there aren‘t multiple elements but only one, access via index is still necessary.

Comment: @CBroe True. Missed that :(

Answer (score 0):

I see there are two issues: the `replace("_s", "")` will replace 1 occurrence of `_s` in the input with empty string, and `_s` actually can match anywhere, even not before `.png`.

Thus, I suggest:

```
var res = str.replace(/_s\.png/g, ".png");
```

Add the `\.png` pattern to the regex and replace with just `.png`.

You may add a `\b` at the end to make sure you match on the word boundary (`/_s\.png\b/g`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all - solution working below - mucked up the getelement too in the q:

```
function yourFunction(){
    var str = document.getElementById("icon").innerHTML;
    var res = str.replace(/_s\.png/g, ".png")
    document.getElementById("icon").innerHTML = res;

    setTimeout(yourFunction, 5000);
}

yourFunction();
```